# Unable to telnet particular server IP from our CentOS 7.2 server

Tags: firewall, centos7, ping, timeout, telnet

I am unable to telnet  a partner server IP (103.x.x.x) from our server.

```
I am getting following error
telnet: connect to address 103.x.x.x: Connection timed out
```

but I am able to telnet other server IP from our server. 
Also I am able to ping that partner server from other server

what will be the reason? i ask the partner check weather our server IP is blocked by their firewall. they checked and told no

I am using CentOS 7.2

Please help me to fix the issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you received a `Connection timed out` error message on telnet but can ping it, there is a firewall somewhere droping your telnet connection.

To discover where there is a firewall, use `tcptraceroute 103.x.x.x 23`.

It is like the common traceroute, but uses TCP packets, not ICMP packets. You will be able to detect where the packets are being droped.